# How to create a range of 5 price ranges from a products table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table with a column for price and master category.

I'd like to query my DB to find the range of prices there are for a given category (or all categories). This range of prices would then be broken into an appropriate number of price-ranges ie £0-£5 £5-£10 etc...

I can't get my head around how to do this; do I need to do this all with php?

**EDIT:** having had a wee think about it, to clarify, I would like to end up so that whatever category is being listed, I can show perhaps 4 price ranges with roughly equal numbers of products in each. I can't get my feeble mind around it :(

Comment: Are there a distinct set of specific prices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the min and max price per category:

```
SELECT category, min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price
from Products
Group BY category
```

For ranges directly in a query you could do something like this

```
SELECT
    category,
    SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as zero-five,
    SUM(CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as five-ten,
    ...
from Products
Group BY category
```

yields

```
Category  zero-five  five-ten
Cat1        2          4
Cat2        3          6
```

or

```
SELECT category, range, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        category,
        CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 0 to 5 THEN '0-5'
             WHEN price BETWEEN 5 to 10 THEN '5-10'
             ...
             ELSE '10+'
        END as range
    FROM products
)
group by category, range
```

yields

```
Category  range count
Cat1       0-5    2      
Cat1       5-10   4      
Cat1       10+    0
Cat2       0-5    3      
Cat2       5-10   6      
Cat2       10+    0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "
SELECT P1.category as category, min(P1.price) as min_price, max(P2.price) as max_price
FROM Products P1 join Products P2 on P1.category=P2.category
Group BY category
";
<table width="300" border="1">
<tr>
<td><b>category</b></td>
<td><b>min_price</b></td>
<td><b>max_price</b></td>
</tr>
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//print data
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['category']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['min_price']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['max_price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: @crazy Sarah, please post your table structure we could help more.

Comment: Hi there, the table is a zencart here's the schema: http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Database_Schema

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your table structure, but this will grab unique prices in your products table:

```
select distinct price from products order by price desc;
```

From here, I would probably start using PHP. How exactly would you prefer to break these prices down into groups?

Comment: I was planning that I'd break it up into 5 or so price ranges with roughly equal amounts of products in each price range.